# CodeIgniter : How to write timestampdiff query in models codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

in phpmyadmin i can run this query

```
Select * from tbl_member where id_group= 'value' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '0' and  '19'
```

but in my model i cannot run this query

```
class Member_m extends CI_Model {

    function select_member($id_group,$age_min,$age_max){
        $condition = " TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '".$age_min."' and '".$age_max."' ";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_member');
        $this->db->where('id_group',$id_group);
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query;
    }
}
```

I tried to take a member of the minimum age to the age of maximal, for example, I wanted to take the members of the member from the age of 10 years up to the age of 19 years .. any one can help me?

Comment: Correct condition name in the where clause. It should be $condition not $conditionn.

Comment: Can you expand on what's not working? Are you getting any errors? Also, shouldn't your statement be `BETWEEN '10' and '19'` if you want the range to be `10 <= age <= 19`?

Comment: @AT-2016 already repaired, but still can not

Comment: @px06 I have an error in my sql sintak, I do not know what went wrong

Comment: Can you please post the entire error that you're getting?

Comment: this my sql error :
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tanggal_lahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN "9" and "10"' at line 4
 `SELECT * FROM (tbl_anggota) WHERE  id_cr = 'M2S' AND '`' '`TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tanggal_lahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN "9" and "10" `

Comment: Well if you read the error it says `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tanggal_lahir, CURDATE())`, it's trying to compare a date to the string "tanggal_lahir".. That won't work. I think your `birthday` column is referencing something other than a birthdate. Please check.